# SQL. How to detect user's language?

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

How to detect user's language? I need to select english text If user's language is *en-Us* and lithuanian text if *lt-Lt*. I'm trying to do something like this:

```
SELECT 
CASE WHEN Language = 'en-US' THEN 'English text'
     WHEN Language = 'lt-LT' THEN 'Lithuanian text'
END
```

In this case I got following error: `Invalid column name 'Language'.`

Comment: You have to do this on the front end app.   SQL cannot detect information about the user's computer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following methods:

Method 1: Use system function @@language

```
select @@language
```

The system function @@language contains the name of the current language of the server

Method 2 : Use sys.syslanguages view

```
select name from sys.syslanguages 
where langid=@@langid
```

The system function @@langid will have the id for current language

Comment: Thank you for an answer, but this checking only system's language? I've tried to achieve user's computer's language. For example I've tried to change my keyboard language to lithuanian, but It always returning `us_english`

Comment: Right, sql server is not able to determine the language setting of the client machine. If you need this on the sql side you need to get that information to sql...often as a parameter.